# Elseif error can't fix it

Tags: php, if-statement

My PHP code dosen't work for some reason, I get an error on `elseif`. I can't really figure it out because I've never used `elseif` but I've saw at YouTube you can use it but I really want some help to figure this one out, but it worked fine before i set `$status1-2 = closedmsg1-2`.
Do you know the answer or another way to do the `$status1-2 = closedmsg1-2`?
I've also searched a bit for "String Replacer" or "String Set" but i can't find it.

```
<?php
//Made by Arnem\\

//\\Options//\\
$closed = 2000;
$opend = 1500;
$openmsg = '<p class=customfont>Streaming status: Online</p>';
$closemsg = '<h1 class=customfont2>Streaming is currently offline!</h1>';
$closemsg2 = '<p class=customfont>Streaming status: Offline</p>';
//DO NOT CONFIGURE UNDER THIS LINE!\\
$time = gmdate(H)+1 . gmdate(i);
if ($time>$closed)
$status1 = $closemsg;
$status2 = $closemsg2;
elseif ($time<$opend)
$status1 = $closemsg;
$status2 = $closemsg2;
else
$status2 = $openmsg;

echo$status1;
echo $status2;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if ($time>$closed){
$status1 = $closemsg;
$status2 = $closemsg2;
}elseif ($time<$opend){
$status1 = $closemsg;
$status2 = $closemsg2;
}else{
// are you missing $status1 here? could be why its not working
$status2 = $openmsg;
}
```

You were missing the braces `{}`. The only time you can go without them is when its a single statement if/else.

Comment: Ty :) works but now the status1 thing aint working any ideas on that one?

Comment: I'm assuming you're reaching the last `else` part of your statement and `$status1` isn't defined there. Check my edit.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise i was missing it

Answer (score 1):

You need braces (only single statement branches can go without them).

```
if ($time>$closed) {
    $status1 = $closemsg;
    $status2 = $closemsg2;
} elseif ($time<$opend) {
    $status1 = $closemsg;
    $status2 = $closemsg2;
} else {
    $status2 = $openmsg;
}
```